# How to pass JSON Array in Retrofit GET request?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have an URL int the format https://example.com/wp-json/newapp/v1/home/?required=

I need to pass required= [{"a":"p1","b":"q1","c":"1"},{"a":"p2","b":"q2","c":"1"},{"a":"p3","b":"q3","c":"1"}]

I'm using Retrofit.

I tried using this

Retrofit instance class

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://example.com/wp-json/newapp/v1/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Endpoints

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("home/?required={value}")
    Call<HomeResponse> getHome(@Path("value") HomeParams[] homeParams);
}
```

Created a class to pass parameters

```
public class HomeParams {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;


public HomeParams(String a, String b, String c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Webservice Request

```
private void getHome() {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        HomeParams[] homeParams = new HomeParams[]{
                new HomeParams("p1","q1","1"),
                new HomeParams("p2","q2","1"),
                new HomeParams("p3","q3","4")

        };
        Log.e(TAG, "getHome: "+homeParams );
        Call<HomeResponse> call = apiInterface.getHome(homeParams);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<HomeResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HomeResponse>call, Response<HomeResponse> response) {
                HomeResponse homeResponse = response.body();
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: --------------" );


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<HomeResponse>call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getLocalizedMessage() );
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm getting this error

```
04-06 22:33:10.121 4916-4916/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.new.app, PID: 4916
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.new.app/com.new.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "required={value}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
                                                 for method ApiInterface.getHome
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2560)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "required={value}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
                                                 for method ApiInterface.getHome
                                                 at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:695)
                                                 at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:686)
                                                 at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseHttpMethodAndPath(ServiceMethod.java:296)
                                                 at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseMethodAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:241)
                                                 at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:169)
                                                 at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
                                                 at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
                                                 at $Proxy0.getHome(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.new.app.MainActivity.getHome(MainActivity.java:154)
                                                 at com.new.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6543)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2513)
                                                    ... 9 more
```

I tried using @Query also. 
How can it be done?

Comment: Provide error logs if possible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the way you are sending params are wrong. As per your URL, **required** is a query param so need to be sent as same.

**Use this:**

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("home/")
    Call<HomeResponse> getHome(@Query("required") HomeParams[] homeParams);
}
```

Comment: Is the way I'm sending values for the parameter correct?

Comment: HomeParam[] seems to be right. I would suggest try annotating fields (a, b & c) in HomeParam i.e @SerializedName("a"). 

Have you tested with my answer?

Comment: Yes, I'm not getting the error, I was getting earlier. But now I'm not getting any response to the call.